# What does repair install replace? (Windows server 2008)

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows

I think some of my system files are corrupted.  The main problem I'm noticing is that when I try to open the Network and Sharing Center, a blank window opens that says "The page failed to load".  I did a system file check, and it said it found errors it can't repair.  The CBS file is loooong, and I don't know how do do anything with it anyway.

I think a repair install is in order.  I don't mind if I need to re-install third party applications.  But will a repair install also require me to re-install roles, features and users?

Comment: What is a CBS file?

Comment: The system file check makes a log file called cbs.log that it dumps information about the scan into.  It's long, and somewhere in it it tells what files are missing.